# Cambiar colores de filas en un Treeview Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Quiero intercalar lineas siendo una linea con fondo blanco, una con fondo gris, una con fondo blanco y asi sucesivamente hasta el total de filas en el treeview. Deberia quedar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*(edit que hice en photshop)*

y este es mi codigo, genero las filas con un bucle For.

```
#Crea el Treeview
arbol = tkrttk.Treeview(ventana)

#Crea un estilo para ajustar la fuente de los encabezados de 
columna
estilo = tkrttk.Style()
estilo.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Arial", 10))#Cambiar a 2 para Movil

#Establece una ID a cada columna
arbol["columns"] = ("Column2", "Column3", "Column4")

#Estilo para ajustar la fuente al Treeview
arbol.tag_configure('fuente', font=("Arial", 10))  #Cambiar a 2 para Movil

#Crea las Columnas del Treeview
arbol.column("#0", width = 1)
arbol.column("Column2", width = 100)
arbol.column("Column3", width = 50)
arbol.column("Column4", width = 100)

#Encabezados de Columnas del Treeview
arbol.heading("#0", text = "Fecha")
arbol.heading("Column2", text = "Infectados")
arbol.heading("Column3", text = "Tasa %")
arbol.heading("Column4", text = "Predicciones")

#Crea filas por cada día que haya en la lista de dias
for fecha in Lista_Chiledef:

    arbol.insert("", len(Lista_Chiledef), text = fecha, tag = 'fuente', values = (datos[Lista_Chiledef.index(fecha)], resir[Lista_Chiledef.index(fecha)], ris[Lista_Chiledef.index(fecha)]))

#Empaqueta el Treeview
arbol.pack(side = tkr.TOP, fill = tkr.BOTH)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para asignar los colores de fondo a cada fila se usan etiquetas también, al igual que haces para la fuente.

```
arbol.tag_configure("gray", background="gray")
arbol.tag_configure("white", background="white")
```

Luego en el ciclo alternas, puedes usar el índice y el resto de la división entre dos:

```
color = "white" if indice % 2 else "gray"
arbol.insert(tag=('fuente', color), ...)
```

dónde `indice` es el índice del elemento de tu lista a insertar o el índice de la fila del `Treeview`.

Te dejo una forma más genérica, que te serviría para cualquier números de colores cíclicos, usando `itertools.cycle`:

```
import itertools
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


lista_chile_def = [
    "Mar3", "Mar4", "Mar5", "Mar6",
    "Mar7", "Mar8", "Mar9", "Mar10"
    ]
datos = [1,  3,  4,  5,  7,  10, 13, 17]
resir = ["", 3.0, 1.3333, 1.25, 1.4, 1.4286, 1.3, 1.3077]
ris = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x220")
arbol = ttk.Treeview(ventana)

colores_filas = ("gray",  "white")
for color in colores_filas:
    arbol.tag_configure(color, background=color)

estilo = ttk.Style()
estilo.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Arial", 10))
arbol["columns"] = ("Column2", "Column3", "Column4")
arbol.tag_configure('fuente', font=("Arial", 10))

arbol.column("#0", width=1)
arbol.column("Column2", width=100)
arbol.column("Column3", width=50)
arbol.column("Column4", width=100)

arbol.heading("#0", text = "Fecha")
arbol.heading("Column2", text = "Infectados")
arbol.heading("Column3", text = "Tasa %")
arbol.heading("Column4", text = "Predicciones")

colores = itertools.cycle(colores_filas)
for color, fecha, *values in zip(colores, lista_chile_def, datos, resir, ris):
    arbol.insert(
        "", tk.END, text=fecha, tag=('fuente',  color), values=values
        )

arbol.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo un problema con el parametro "Background", no se visualiza el color en las lineas, ni siquiera poniendolo directamente en el "Tag_configure" que ya tengo, no me suelta ningun error ni nada, solo se queda en blanco asi le haya puesto el color

Comment: Incluso copié y pegue todo ese código (el de itertool) en un archivo en blanco y no se coloreaba nada, quedaba todo en blanco

Comment: Seguí probando y me di cuenta que el error igualmente sucede con el parametro "Foreground"

Comment: Hay un bug documentado ( resuelto) con este tema. Básicamente depende de las versiones de Tk y python instaladas. Reinstalar Tk no lo resuelve porque el problema podría estar en la versión que lleva 'de serie' python. Puedes leer más, y cómo solucionarlo en este enlace: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1286